# Can't display canvas object

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Guys Here is a function which should display a red ball on the frame, but it isn't doing so, I am watching a tutorial to do that, I am doing everything exactly as he does but I can't figure out what is the problem here.. Please I need to know this. If somebody can understand please help..

```js
var canvas,ctx,w,h,game=true;
var ball;
var BALL = function(x,y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.color = "red";
    this.radius = 10;
    this.vx = 3;
    this.vy = -4;
}


window.onload = init;
function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  w = canvas.width;
  h = canvas.height;
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ball = new BALL(w/2,h/2+50);
  beginGame();
}

function beginGame(){
  if(game){  
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);

      ball.x+=ball.vx;
      ball.y+=ball.vy;

      if((ball.x+ball.radius)+ball.vx>w || (ball.x-ball.radius)+ball.vx<0){
          ball.vx = -ball.vx;
      }

      ctx.fillStyle = ball.color;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(ball.x,ball.y,ball.radus,0,2*Math.PI,true);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fill();

      window.requestAnimationFrame(beginGame);

  }else{
    //Game Over
  }

}// End of beginGame function
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>არკანოიდი</title>
<script src='tools.js'></script>
<script src='jquery-1.11.2.min.js' language='javascript' > </script>

<style>
canvas {
    border: 1px solid silver;
}
</style>
</head>

<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don' know if it will fix everything but your canvas is outside of your body tags.

Comment: found it, you misspelled radius in the arc function parameter

Comment: thank you so much! that fixed it.. I wasted so many hours looking for a mistake..

Answer (score 0):

for script tags:
1. don't use language='javascript'. this is not needed.
2. If you do want to explicitly declare it as javascript, then use type="text/javascript". This is automatically the case, so you don't even need to do that.
3. Put the canvas inside the body tags.
4. use window.addEventListener("load", init) instead of window.onload(init)
5.inside startgame function:

```
function beginGame()
{
    // previous lines omitted...
    ball = new BALL(x, y);
    // other lines here...
}
```